# C++ import library by source

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and wonder if it is good practice to include a library by source code. If it is, what would be the best way to achieve this? Just copying in a subfolder and using include?

In my special case, I have written a small library and I'm going to use it on two different microprocessors. Compiling the library separately, copying all headers and using this "package" seems to be overkill for me.

Comment: No, libraries are exactly intended to be compiled separately and linked with the final target.

Comment: Some libraries are 'header-only', e.g. many of the [boost libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/). This is out of necessity, as they rely heavily of templates, but makes for longer compilation times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling the library separately is what should be done.

It's not *that* overkill either : you're just compiling the `.o` files for your library, then wrapping them in an archive and handling that archive around.

Comment: Thanks for providing the best practice. But in my special case (I'm not really used to automate build process and cross compilation), I will do it as @Marco guessed.

Comment: @andiwand I'd take that as an opportunity to try it, but as you wish ;)

Comment: haha ur right, it should be. :) but right now I really like to get this work first. (I hope) I will do this later on this project.

Answer (score 1):

Normally libraries are used as libraries because it is much easier and comfortable that way. If you are using dynamic libraries (.dll or .so) things get even better because you can replace libraries on the fly and things should continue to work smoothly.

You decided to use code repositories instead of libraries which means probably more work for you. If you are happy this way that's OK, but just make sure you do not break any license, some lgpl packages (like Qt) clearly 
require their libraries to be linked dynamically.

The best way to do this: hard to say but in your place I would probably use git and include the libraries as submodules.

Comment: Using git and including the library as submodule is actual exactly what i thought about. I'm not very used to write makefiles or other automatic build process. Especially with cross compilation. I think it would be the best way in my case...

Answer (score 1):

Just `#include`ing source code is a bad idea since it means just to copy the code into your own, things can go wrong that way. For example if there is a static variable somewhere in the library code and the same named static variable in your code you will have a conflict.

Instead you should probably compile the library separately and link it, possibly the same way as you would do anyway (ie you build the library and then you link with that library). But the light weight alternative would be just to compile the additional C++ files and then link the object files together to an executable. Details on how you do that is compiler specific.

There's valid reasons for including the library source in this way, for example if your project needs to modify the library during development it would be easier to do so if the rebuilding of the library is done as a part of the build process of the project. With a well designed build process the library shouldn't have to be rebuilt unless there are actual changes to it.

Comment: I think include was the wrong word. I'm not using the #include statement to source files. I just keep the source in a subdirectory and import the headers from there. In my build process the library is build once and since it is not going to change from there, never build again.

Answer (score 0):

The value of a library is in part that you link it more often than you compile it, leading to a net saving.

If you control all the source, then whatever build process works best for you is fine.

Comment: This is a nice rule to remember, thanks! I think I will leave it with git and submodules since I still compile it only on changes. And we are talking about ~1K lines and not ~1M lines.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with  [πάντα ῥεῖ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1413395/%CF%80%CE%AC%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B1-%E1%BF%A5%CE%B5%E1%BF%96) but I'll also add that the reason it is bad practice is because the compiled library can be stored in your computer in a common location and used by tons of different programs, thereby reducing the amount of data your computer has to store, in memory as well as RAM(if more than one running program uses the same library).  An example is openGL which is a library that many games use and is probably already in your system somewhere.  If you use windows, software installers link up these libraries to their programs and add them if you don't have them.  If you use linux, you will be notified if libraries are missing and prompted to install them.  All of that aside, you can, technically use un-compiled libraries but that introduces a number of potential licensing problems as well as additional problems with THEIR dependencies.

Comment: since I use only my own code, there are no licensing problems

Answer (score 0):

By copying source code to other projects and "mixing" it with other source code will stop this library from being a "library". Later on you will be tempted to make a small change in one copy (for CPU) or fix a bug and forget to do the same in the other copy.

There might be additional consideration but you should try to keep the code in one place. Do not Repeat Yourself (DRY) is a very strong and fundamental principal of software engineering with many benefits.

Comment: "Do not Repeat Yourself" is what i want to achieve. I'm not very used to automate build process and support cross compilation. As @Marco guessed, I am using git and submodules. So if I want to change the library, I would do this in its repository.

Comment: The solution to avoid DRY could be to put the "library" source separately into source control, many VCSes support pulling together a project consisting of multiple repositories.